# How do monsters move on local paths to side boards?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-mountains-madness, eldritch-horror-under-the-pyramids

How do monsters move along local paths to traverse the side boards in expansion games such as when effects instruct players to move a monster toward investigators?
For instance, a local path connects space 17 and Cairo, and an investigator would effectively be able to teleport from one to the other at no action cost.
Would a monster on space 17 be allowed to, for the cost of 1 move, travel to Cairo (or would it cost no moves)?
The fire vampire moves two spaces toward the nearest investigator, so would an appropriate step count be to move him from Shanghai to space 17, then to Cairo for a total of 2 spaces?

Comment: I feel like I answered my own question in considering that I meant to ask whether traveling the local paths cost 1 or 0 moves (as it in a way costs the investigators 0 moves). I clarified a portion of the question, but it does seem to be obvious now that it shouldn't be 0 moves along these paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each location is a space, so regardless of what type of path exists, a monster moving from Shanghai to Space 17 and then to Cairo has moved 2 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it doesn't matter what path as long as it's the least number of paths and if it does seem to matter, decide together.  If indecision Lead Investigator would decide.

p8 of reference guide:

> "When investigators make a decision as a group, the Lead Investigator
>   makes the final decision."

p16 of the rulebook:

> "The Lead Investigator decides all disputes."

I would further say that this is an excellent application of the general rule, if there are two paths pick the one that harms the investigators more.  If they're equally harmful, go with the above.  I wouldn't spend too long deciding on "equally harmful" either=)

Comment: This seems like a good policy when deciding which victim is closer, at least as far as using the shortest path to a location in order to decide how far a location officially is from a monster. I don't know that it necessarily "harms" the team more necessarily, and picking where monsters go often lies at the discretion of the lead, I believe, when the guiding rules for which direction it moves results in many options. So, in these cases it seems allowable for the lead to pick the path to his greatest benefit.

Comment: @Joey It can definitely be overanalyzed=)

Answer (score 0):

As the rules don't state nothing special about monsters and local paths, you don't do anything special.
Monsters treat all paths equally.